# Submitting a different form

Tags: html, forms

I have a form with checkboxes. I don't want the submit button to be placed near the checkboxes but at the bottom of the page, with lots of content in between. Is there a way to to this? So I guess what I need is 2 forms, one submitting the other one.

Comment: yes you can use the <pre> tag which will give you kind of formatting as you want.
<pre> code of you button</pre>
<body>
<pre>code of your button</pre>
</body>

Comment: @sachit: How exactly is a `<pre>` tag related to this question?! Using that tag to format anything but plain text is horrible anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML5 you can use `form="id-of-a-form"` in a `<input>` element to make it belong to that form even without being a child element of the form. Of course this won't work in old browser so you might want to add some JavaScript to shim this behaviour in those browsers.

Depending on what you want to do you could also simply keep the form tag open the whole time, i.e. basically wrap most of your body in the form. This only works if it does not result in nested forms!

Comment: I think this is the best answer if you're using html5 and don't care about old non-html5 browsers (or create some conditional js for them).

Comment: Doesn't even need to be conditionsl - `submit()` and `preventDefault` do the job while keeping it working for people who disabled js but have a modern browser

Answer (score 2):

If you're not against using javascript, just make a button and let it submit the form via `document.FormNameHere.submit()` (see [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml))

Answer (score 0):

You just need a big form containing the checkboxes, the submit button and everything in between.

Comment: But I have LOTS of content in between, including several forms. Is that okay?

Comment: No, that only works if you just have one form - nesting them isn't allowed.

Comment: Having forms between the controls of other forms is often indicative of a hard-to-understand UI that needs a redesign.